# Moving between windows in the same html file

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm starting using jQuery Mobile using this tutorial:
[Displaying windows](http://the-jquerymobile-tutorial.org/jquery-mobile-tutorial-CH02.php)

But I'm having a problem now that I don't understand.

When a have the code below in the file name `index.html` I'm able to navigate beteween windows, but if I have the same code in a file named, for instance, `index3.html`, this doesnt work anymore....

Anyone knows the reason? Any solution?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title2</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div data-role=page id=win>
        <!-- Default theme -->
        <div data-role=header>
            <h1>Default theme</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role=content>
            <p>
                Window content
            </p>
            <a href=#wina> Goto "a" theme </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role=page id=wina data-add-back-btn=true>
        <div data-role=header data-theme=a>
            <h1> "a" theme </h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role=content data-theme=a>
            <p>
                Window content
            </p>
            <a href=#winb> Goto "b" theme </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role=page id=winb data-add-back-btn=true>
        <div data-role=header data-theme=b>
            <h1> "b" theme </h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role=content data-theme=b>
            <p>
                Window content
            </p>
            <a href=#winc> Goto "c" theme </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role=page id=winc data-add-back-btn=true>
        <div data-role=header data-theme=c>
            <h1> "c" theme </h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role=content data-theme=c>
            <p>
                Window content
            </p>
            <a href=#wind> Goto "d" theme </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role=page id=wind data-add-back-btn=true>
        <div data-role=header data-theme=d>
            <h1> "d" theme </h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role=content data-theme=d>
            <p>
                Window content
            </p>
            <a href=#wine> Goto "e" theme </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role=page id=wine data-add-back-btn=true>
        <div data-role=header data-theme=e>
            <h1> "e" theme </h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role=content data-theme=e>
            <p>
                Window content
            </p>
            <p>
                End of themes
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update**
I noticed now that the problem just happens when come to this window from another page. When I enter directly the URL of the `index3.html` it works fine. The code from the other page is:

```
        <div data-role=content>
            <a href=index3.html> Goto default themes</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Make your choice: single page navigation or multi page navigation. Both solutions at same time generate duplicate elements IDs

Comment: @grigno, But if I have different IDs shoudn't this solve the problem? I have different IDs on each page. I don't understand why I can have both navigations... Did you see my edit?

Comment: ok, sorry I did not read it right. I know you wanted both navigation type at the same time...